# Informix Innovator-c and SAN storage: How can we increase Innovator-C parallelism in high latency disk IO situations

Tags: informix, san

When using Innovator-C against SAN storage (which is unavoidable in some cloud infrastructure situations) on a Linux (CentOS 6.x) system, write latency becomes the bottleneck in performance (we've seen initialization of a 1/2 TiB cooked dbspace take over an hour, with low 100 MBps throughput, even though the storage benchmarks much  higher MBPs with fio, when configured for lots of parallel large block size writes).

We're interested in increasing parallelism for the initialization as well as ensuring maximum parallelism for operations. fio does well with an iodepth of 64, keeping lots of writes in flight against the disk; this leads to considering increasing AIOVPS dramatically (this is a cooked file and Innovator-C does not support directio, so I conclude the AIOVPs will be used for access to this dbspace).

The following are stats from the initialization (the only dn use has been installation and creating dbspaces; the only significant dbspace is the single 1/2 TiB dbspace in question).

```
$ onstat -g iov 

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8IE -- On-Line -- Up 7 days 
01:58:12 -- 1907928 Kbytes 

AIO I/O vps: 
class/vp/id s  io/s totalops  dskread dskwrite  dskcopy  wakeups  io/wup  errors tempops 
 fifo  7  0 i   0.0        0        0        0        0        1   0.0       0        0 
  kio -1  0 i   0.0    29687     2058    27629        0    89384   0.3       0        0 
  msc  6  0 i   0.0      496        0        0        0      497   1.0       0      496 
  aio  5  0 i   0.0    18613     6796     8349        0    17553   1.1       0        0 
  aio  8  1 i   0.0     2215      326     1878        0     2015   1.1       0        0 
  aio  9  2 i   0.0     2282       54     2227        0     1511   1.5       0        0 
  aio 10  3 i   0.0     1978       30     1947        0     1331   1.5       0        0 
  aio 11  4 i   0.0     1796       20     1773        0     1222   1.5       0        0 
  aio 12  5 i   0.0     1598       20     1578        0     1149   1.4       0        0 
  pio  4  0 i   0.0        0        0        0        0        1   0.0       0        0 
  lio  3  0 i   0.0        0        0        0        0        1   0.0       0        0 

$ onstat -g glo 

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8IE -- On-Line -- Up 7 days 02:18:28 -- 1907928 Kbytes 

MT global info: 
sessions threads  vps      lngspins 
0        35       13       0 

          sched calls     thread switches yield 0   yield n   yield forever 
total:    12378189        9602519         2819012   7987793   169699 
per sec:  57              45              12        39        0 

Virtual processor summary: 
 class       vps       usercpu   syscpu    total 
 cpu         1         62.66     7.21      69.87 
 aio         6         8.25      22.12     30.37 
 lio         1         2.10      3.66      5.76 
 pio         1         1.57      3.83      5.40 
 adm         1         5.21      22.91     28.12 
 soc         1         27.90     26.76     54.66 
 msc         1         0.02      0.01      0.03 
 fifo        1         1.75      3.67      5.42 
 total       13        109.46    90.17     199.63 

Individual virtual processors: 
 vp    pid       class       usercpu   syscpu    total     Thread    Eff 
 1     1800      cpu         62.66     7.21      69.87     127.73    54% 
 2     1801      adm         5.21      22.91     28.12     0.00       0% 
 3     1802      lio         2.10      3.66      5.76      5.76     100% 
 4     1803      pio         1.57      3.83      5.40      5.40     100% 
 5     1804      aio         1.10      4.87      5.97      75.01      7% 
 6     1805      msc         0.02      0.01      0.03      0.04      73% 
 7     1806      fifo        1.75      3.67      5.42      5.42     100% 
 8     1807      aio         1.22      3.73      4.95      18.49     26% 
 9     1808      aio         1.27      3.55      4.82      15.46     31% 
 10    1809      aio         1.60      3.40      5.00      15.12     33% 
 11    1810      aio         1.61      3.27      4.88      14.03     34% 
 12    1811      aio         1.45      3.30      4.75      13.19     36% 
 13    1812      soc         27.90     26.76     54.66     NA         NA 
                 tot         109.46    90.17     199.63
```

Any thoughts/advice?

Many thanks -

Stephen